# Spinner showing this error: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want the spinner to open up by itself when I run the activity without the user having to click on it before it drops down, so I'm using the performClick() method but it's showing this error:

Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

What should I do? Here is my code

```
public class FacilityComplaint extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Spinner spinner1;

private static final String[] suggestions = {"Select from suggestions", "Switch not working",
        "Switch faulty", "Switch light not working", "Switch handle faulty"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facility_complaint);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FacilityComplaint.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, suggestions);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner1.performClick();
}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //do something
            break;

        case 1:
            //do something
            break;

        case 2:
            //do something
            break;

        case 3:
            //do something
            break;

        case 4:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Comment: Try calling `spinner1.performClick();` in `onResume()`, And make sure it is called only once.

Comment: i'm calling performClick() when an ImageView is clicked on and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.